# How do I enable Python on IDA 6.8?

Tags: ida, idapython

I have a `python` dir within IDA 6.8 folder with `idaapi.py`, `idautils.py`, and `idc.py`. IDA doesn't seem to pick the Python scripting by default.

How do I enable it?

Comment: IDA 6.8 was released in 2014 -- 8 years ago. Have you considered upgrading to a more recent version?

Comment: Are you talking about Python 2 or 3? The capability to use Python 3 was introduced in one of the 7.x versions (could be 7.2 not sure about this).

Comment: @Robert For 6.8 it uses Python 2.7. It even has an installer for it with the distribution. Not helping to setting it up though...

Comment: @RolfRolles I just didn't want to disturb my current setup. Since I was doing it over the years and I am not sure I needed any new features until now, which is not that new either as Python support was there for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with the help of [this page](https://hex-rays.com/blog/ida-and-common-python-issues/)

At the end of the day it was

1. pointing to python 3.8 installation instead of Python 2.7 although both were installed on the machine
2. python27.dll was not in the package I've used to install Python 2.7. Had to reinstall it
3. had to remove PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME completely and leave only PATH pointing to Python 2.7 installation